# Selectively allocate dimensions for multi-dimensional array at construction

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Java supports multi-dimensional arrays, which are represented as "arrays of arrays".  For instance, I can create an array of String arrays using the following code:

```
int rows = ...
int cols = ...
String[][] array2d = new String[rows][cols];
```

What I'd like to do is have the second dimension be "nulled out".  In other words, a for-loop like `for(String[] array : array2d) System.err.println(array);` would print out:

```
null
...
null
```

The reason I'd like to do this is because I have already allocated a bunch of `String[]` instances that I want to just drop into `array2d`.  I have a couple of solutions but both seem sub-optimal for the following reasons:

**Solution 1**

I could just do something like `String[][] array2d = new String[rows][0]`, use a for-loop to null out the first dimension, and populate the rows later, but this seems ugly to me because Java will create a new empty `String[]` for every row, and I really don't need it to.

**Solution 2**

I could also do something like `String[][] array2d = new String[][]{null, null, ... null}`, but this is even worse because I have to hard code the length of the first dimension of `array2d` via the bracketed section of code, which is disgusting.

I recognize that this isn't a huge problem, especially when the dimensionality is small, and any programmer worth his salt would choose some other construct over creating arrays of many dimensions.  I'm mostly just curious if there is a way to partially allocate dimensions of a multi-dimensional array at construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest solution possible:

```
int rows = ...
String[][] array2d = new String[rows][];
```

If you don't initialize the second dimension, you array will have `null` entries in dimension 1.